# Finding blank arrays within ruby arrays Rails 4

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am trying build a sentence out of 3 arrays with the count of each array.

```
cats = Cat.all 
dogs = Dog.all
birds = Bird.all 

animals = ["#{cats.count} Cats", "#{dogs.count} Dogs", "#{birds.count} Birds"]

sentence = animals.each.map{ |r| r  }.join(",  ")
```

Right now, this works, but if I have no cats sentence outputs to

```
"O Cats, 5 Dogs, 4 Birds"
```

and I'ld like it to just say:

```
"5 Dogs & 4 Birds"
```

or, at the very least:

```
"5 Dogs, 4 Birds"
```

I feel like I might need to use an array of hashes, but I'm a bit lost.

Comment: something simpler is to declare your animals array empty like `animals = []`, and then add elements one by one like: `animals << "#{cats.count} Cats" if cats.count > 0`. It all depends on how your implementation is done, so, this might work or not for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need a hash.

```
cats = Cat.all 
dogs = Dog.all
birds = Bird.all

animals = {
  cats: cats.count,
  dogs: dogs.count,
  birds: birds.count
}

sentence = animals.reject{|k, v| v.zero?}
                  .map{|k, v| "#{v} #{k.to_s.capitalize}"}
                  .join(', ')
```

My suggestion: keep data as data till the last moment, so that you can have maximum flexibility to display it in various ways. I feel that the `animals` in your code thinks rendering too soon.

Comment: FYI: `[Cat, Bird, Dog].map { |c| [c.class.name.pluralize, c.count].select { |a,b| b > 0 }.map(&:join).join(",")`. This is overly clever but parts of it are definitely worth employing to shorten the creation of the hash.

Comment: perhaps use `zero?` here.

Comment: @sagarpandya82 Oh I didn't know that there's the method `Numeric#zero?`. It does make the code a bit cleaner. Thanks.

Comment: @meagar That's an interesting one liner. I didn't do this because I thought maybe the local variable `cats` and `dogs` and `birds` have other uses in OP's program.

Answer (score 2):

To get `"5 Dogs, 4 Birds"`, you can do

```
sentence = animals.each.map{ |r| /^0\s/.match(r) ? nil : r  }.compact.join(", ")
```

The regex matches anything that starts with `0` and a space. If there is a match, return nil, or return the original string. The `compact` method removes `nil` elements from the array, and finally you join the elements.

If you want `5 Dogs & 4 Birds`, you can define a method that performs that function.

```
def english_join(array)
  return array.to_s if array.nil? or array.length <= 1
  array[0..-2].join(", ") + " & " + array[-1]
end
```

Then you can do

```
sentence = english_join(animals.each.map{ |r| /^0\s/.match(r) ? nil : r  }.compact)
```

If you have 0 cats, 5 dogs, and 4 birds, this returns `5 Dogs & 4 Birds`.

If you have 2 cats, 5 dogs, and 4 birds, this returns `2 Cats, 5 Dogs & 4 Birds`

Comment: I'm torn between these two answers.  As you are both right.  Plus your english join is right on.